# Recursion: Sum of series of n terms

Tags: algorithm, recursion

**Recursive function needed**

**Series is**: 1 + 2*3 + 3*4*5 + 4*5*6*7 + ....

Find the sum of the series for n recursively. I am not able to think of what              parameters should I pass in function.

**My approach**

I thought that I should pass n, number of terms to be multiplied but what I am not able to think of is how should I + and * in same function and what will my return statement is?

Comment: You send the first number which is also the number of numbers to multiply...

Answer (score 2):

```
function F(n, nmax, prod): Int
   //prod = (prod div n) * (2 * n) * (2 * n + 1)  simpler:  
   prod = prod * 2 * (2 * n + 1)  
   if n = nmax - 1
      return prod
   else
      return prod + F(n+1, nmax,  prod)

output F(1, 7, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static int GetCaluculationProduct(int n)
{
    int result = 1, temp = n;

    if (n == 1)
        return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result *= temp;
        temp++;
    }

    return result + GetCaluculationProduct(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with 2 recursive functions: one for the sum, the other for the product.

**SUM**

```
public int sum_recurs(int _n)
{
if (_n==1) return 1;

return sum_recurs (_n-1)+ sub_sum_recurs(_n);
}
```

**PRODUCT**

```
public int sub_sum_recurs(int _n)
{
if (_n==2) return 2*3;

return sub_sum_recurs(_n-1)/(_n-1)*(2*_n-1)*(2*_n-2);
}
```

**DIRECT FORMULA CALCULATION**

thanks to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590673/formula-to-calculate-directly-1-2-cdot-3-3-cdot-4-cdot-5-4-cdot-5-c#1590687

[image]