# Exponential integral and gamma function

Tags: java, math, numerical-methods, exponential, gamma-function

In order to solve this problem, without iteration:
[Recursion: Sum of series of n terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480831/recursion-sum-of-series-of-n-terms/34481682#34481682)

> calculating for a given n: 1 + 2*3 + 3*4*5 + 4*5*6*7 + ... +
>   n*(n+1)*...*(2n-1)

with this mathematical answer:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590673/formula-to-calculate-directly-1-23-345-4567-nn1-2n#1590687

It here a library in java to get Exponential integral and Gamma function ?

as in this formula:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Q55ZYR3.png]

Thanks

Comment: Google Java gamma (not gramma) function library and the first few hits will likely help. The Apache library is usually a good bet, but why are you asking this here? Why not first Google this yourself? Voting to close as off-topic since you're asking for outside library search help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels , have you read the begining of my question ? on google, java exponential integral => returns my question, and not evident answer ... Yes, gamma is more common !

Answer (score 3):

[Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) library has [Gamma](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/math3/special/Gamma.html) class.

I have adapted code from [Exponential Integrals](http://www.mymathlib.com/functions/exponential_integrals.html) page from C to Java for Ei(x):

```
/**
 *
 */
package wilx.math.exponential.integrals;

/**
 * @author wilx
 */
public class ExponentialIntegrals
{
    // Internally Defined Constants //
    static final double DBL_EPSILON = Math.ulp(1.0);
    static final double epsilon = 10.0 * DBL_EPSILON;
    static final double DBL_MAX = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // double xExponential_Integral_Ei( double x ) //
    // //
    // Description: //
    // The exponential integral Ei(x) is the integral with integrand //
    // exp(t) / t //
    // where the integral extends from -inf to x. //
    // Note that there is a singularity at t = 0. Therefore for x > 0, the //
    // integral is defined to be the Cauchy principal value: //
    // lim { I[-inf, -eta] exp(-t) dt / t + I[eta, x] exp(-t) dt / t } //
    // in which the limit is taken as eta > 0 approaches 0 and I[a,b] //
    // denotes the integral from a to b. //
    // //
    // Arguments: //
    // double x The argument of the exponential integral Ei(). //
    // //
    // Return Value: //
    // The value of the exponential integral Ei evaluated at x. //
    // If x = 0.0, then Ei is -inf and -DBL_MAX is returned. //
    // //
    // Example: //
    // double y, x; //
    // //
    // ( code to initialize x ) //
    // //
    // y = xExponential_Integral_Ei( x ); //
    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static double Exponential_Integral_Ei(final double x)
    {
        if (x < -5.0)
        {
            return Continued_Fraction_Ei(x);
        }
        if (x == 0.0)
        {
            return -DBL_MAX;
        }
        if (x < 6.8)
        {
            return Power_Series_Ei(x);
        }
        if (x < 50.0)
        {
            return Argument_Addition_Series_Ei(x);
        }
        return Continued_Fraction_Ei(x);
    }

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // static double Continued_Fraction_Ei( double x ) //
    // //
    // Description: //
    // For x < -5 or x > 50, the continued fraction representation of Ei //
    // converges fairly rapidly. //
    // //
    // The continued fraction expansion of Ei(x) is: //
    // Ei(x) = -exp(x) { 1/(-x+1-) 1/(-x+3-) 4/(-x+5-) 9/(-x+7-) ... }. //
    // //
    // //
    // Arguments: //
    // double x //
    // The argument of the exponential integral Ei(). //
    // //
    // Return Value: //
    // The value of the exponential integral Ei evaluated at x. //
    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private static double Continued_Fraction_Ei(final double x)
    {
        double Am1 = 1.0;
        double A0 = 0.0;
        double Bm1 = 0.0;
        double B0 = 1.0;
        double a = expl(x);
        double b = -x + 1.0;
        double Ap1 = b * A0 + a * Am1;
        double Bp1 = b * B0 + a * Bm1;
        int j = 1;

        a = 1.0;
        while (fabsl(Ap1 * B0 - A0 * Bp1) > epsilon * fabsl(A0 * Bp1))
        {
            if (fabsl(Bp1) > 1.0)
            {
                Am1 = A0 / Bp1;
                A0 = Ap1 / Bp1;
                Bm1 = B0 / Bp1;
                B0 = 1.0;
            }
            else
            {
                Am1 = A0;
                A0 = Ap1;
                Bm1 = B0;
                B0 = Bp1;
            }
            a = -j * j;
            b += 2.0;
            Ap1 = b * A0 + a * Am1;
            Bp1 = b * B0 + a * Bm1;
            j += 1;
        }
        return (-Ap1 / Bp1);
    }

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // static double Power_Series_Ei( double x ) //
    // //
    // Description: //
    // For -5 < x < 6.8, the power series representation for //
    // (Ei(x) - gamma - ln|x|)/exp(x) is used, where gamma is Euler's gamma //
    // constant. //
    // Note that for x = 0.0, Ei is -inf. In which case -DBL_MAX is //
    // returned. //
    // //
    // The power series expansion of (Ei(x) - gamma - ln|x|) / exp(x) is //
    // - Sum(1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/j) (-x)^j / j!, where the Sum extends //
    // from j = 1 to inf. //
    // //
    // Arguments: //
    // double x //
    // The argument of the exponential integral Ei(). //
    // //
    // Return Value: //
    // The value of the exponential integral Ei evaluated at x. //
    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private static double Power_Series_Ei(final double x)
    {
        double xn = -x;
        double Sn = -x;
        double Sm1 = 0.0;
        double hsum = 1.0;
        final double g = 0.5772156649015328606065121;
        double y = 1.0;
        double factorial = 1.0;

        if (x == 0.0)
        {
            return -DBL_MAX;
        }

        while (fabsl(Sn - Sm1) > epsilon * fabsl(Sm1))
        {
            Sm1 = Sn;
            y += 1.0;
            xn *= (-x);
            factorial *= y;
            hsum += (1.0 / y);
            Sn += hsum * xn / factorial;
        }
        return (g + logl(fabsl(x)) - expl(x) * Sn);
    }

    static final double ei[] = { 1.915047433355013959531e2,
        4.403798995348382689974e2, 1.037878290717089587658e3,
        2.492228976241877759138e3, 6.071406374098611507965e3,
        1.495953266639752885229e4, 3.719768849068903560439e4,
        9.319251363396537129882e4, 2.349558524907683035782e5,
        5.955609986708370018502e5, 1.516637894042516884433e6,
        3.877904330597443502996e6, 9.950907251046844760026e6,
        2.561565266405658882048e7, 6.612718635548492136250e7,
        1.711446713003636684975e8, 4.439663698302712208698e8,
        1.154115391849182948287e9, 3.005950906525548689841e9,
        7.842940991898186370453e9, 2.049649711988081236484e10,
        5.364511859231469415605e10, 1.405991957584069047340e11,
        3.689732094072741970640e11, 9.694555759683939661662e11,
        2.550043566357786926147e12, 6.714640184076497558707e12,
        1.769803724411626854310e13, 4.669055014466159544500e13,
        1.232852079912097685431e14, 3.257988998672263996790e14,
        8.616388199965786544948e14, 2.280446200301902595341e15,
        6.039718263611241578359e15, 1.600664914324504111070e16,
        4.244796092136850759368e16, 1.126348290166966760275e17,
        2.990444718632336675058e17, 7.943916035704453771510e17,
        2.111342388647824195000e18, 5.614329680810343111535e18,
        1.493630213112993142255e19, 3.975442747903744836007e19,
        1.058563689713169096306e20 };

    private static double expl(final double x)
    {
        return Math.exp(x);
    }

    private static double fabsl(final double x)
    {
        return Math.abs(x);
    }

    private static double logl(final double x)
    {
        return Math.log(x);
    }

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // static double Argument_Addition_Series_Ei(double x) //
    // //
    // Description: //
    // For 6.8 < x < 50.0, the argument addition series is used to calculate //
    // Ei. //
    // //
    // The argument addition series for Ei(x) is: //
    // Ei(x+dx) = Ei(x) + exp(x) Sum j! [exp(j) expj(-dx) - 1] / x^(j+1), //
    // where the Sum extends from j = 0 to inf, |x| > |dx| and expj(y) is //
    // the exponential polynomial expj(y) = Sum y^k / k!, the Sum extending //
    // from k = 0 to k = j. //
    // //
    // Arguments: //
    // double x //
    // The argument of the exponential integral Ei(). //
    // //
    // Return Value: //
    // The value of the exponential integral Ei evaluated at x. //
    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private static double Argument_Addition_Series_Ei(final double x)
    {
        final int k = (int) (x + 0.5);
        int j = 0;
        final double xx = k;
        final double dx = x - xx;
        double xxj = xx;

        final double edx = expl(dx);
        double Sm = 1.0;
        double Sn = (edx - 1.0) / xxj;
        double term = DBL_MAX;
        double factorial = 1.0;
        double dxj = 1.0;

        while (fabsl(term) > epsilon * fabsl(Sn))
        {
            j++;
            factorial *= j;
            xxj *= xx;
            dxj *= (-dx);
            Sm += (dxj / factorial);
            term = (factorial * (edx * Sm - 1.0)) / xxj;
            Sn += term;
        }

        return ei[k - 7] + Sn * expl(xx);
    }
}
```

Comment: link only answers should be comments, not answers. Regardless, the question should be closed.

Comment: thanks, does it provide exponential integral too ?

Comment: I talked about exponential integral (E) as there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590673/formula-to-calculate-directly-1-2-cdot-3-3-cdot-4-cdot-5-4-cdot-5-c  . E takes one more argument.

Comment: Thanks for this usefull link. In fact, it is not this function but the other, with an extra parameter n double Exponential_Integral_En( double x, int n ). The exponential integral En(x), introduced by Schloemilch, is the integral of exp(-xt) / t^n dt. The parameter n is called the order of the integral. Unfortunately, this is an integer parameter, and some loops based upon it.