# Recursive Function to find sum of nth term using C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define for noIter
#define while noIter

int sumUP(int n)
{
int result;

if (n == -1)
{
    return 0;
}

return result + (3 * sumUP(n - 1) + 2);

int main(){
    
    int n = 0, ret;
    
    while(1){
        printf("Enter a positive integer : ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n < 0)
            break;
        ret = sumUP(n);
        printf("Sum up to %dth term = %d\n", n, ret);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am currently making a program which sums up the term using recursive function. I have programmed few lines but it shows some weird results. The general form of sequence term is 3n + 2 thus when the user enter integer 5 then the result displayed should be 55 (17 + 14 + 11 + 8 + 5). Hereby program should be stopped when the user inputs -1.

I was able to design a condition which will stop the loop when user inputs -1 but I am struggling with the recursive function. What should I change it in order to have correct outputs?

Comment: `#define while noIter` seems like a *very* bad idea to me. In any case,  `sumUP` appears to not have a closing brace, meaning it won't even *compile.* Hence, if you are getting weird results other than compile-time errors, you have *not* posted the code you're using.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480831/recursion-sum-of-series-of-n-terms/34481682

Comment: initializing `result` might be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the facts

- One term is `3n+2`
- `sumUP(n)` will return the sum

The line

```
return result + (3 * sumUP(n - 1) + 2);
```

should be

```
return n <= 0 ? 0 : ((3 * n + 2) + sumUP(n - 1));
}
```

So that it will return results of addition of one term and sum of left terms when there are terms and return 0 when there are no terms.
Also don't forget the `}`.

One more point is that `#define while noIter` should be removed or the `while(1){` and corresponding `}` in the `main` function should be changed to `mainloop:` and `goto mainloop;` to have it compile.

Comment: Sorry for another question but how does it work? I'm not really good at recursive function so I would like to know some details if possible.

Comment: You may need a basic explanation of the *ternary* operator or perhaps just show an example with `if`. (I'll leave that to your capable hands `:)`